# Call jquery function from php page

Tags: php, jquery

I created a jquery function in a js file that is included in a php page.

Js file

```
$( function() {

    function disab(){
        $('input#idname').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

});
```

In my php file I tried to call the disab function in this way but with no success.

```
echo "<script>";
echo "$(function(){";
echo "disab();";
echo "});";
echo "</script>";
```

How can I do this? thanks

Comment: you only need <script>disab();</script>

Comment: is the php echoing out the javascript below the js file? also, if the function is being called on ondocument ready, it doesn't need to be defined on document ready, it can be defined without the `$(function()` wrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all put your funciton outside the `document.ready` function in your js file...so that it is global and can be accessed from anywhere.

```
 function disab(){
    $('input#idname').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 }

 $( function() { .. }); //use if needed..
```

and call the function inside `<script>` tag in php file

```
 <?php
 //all you php related codes
 ...
 ?>
 <script>
    $(function(){
        disab();
    });
 </script>
```

and most important, use `prop()` instead of `attr()` ... if you are using latest version of jquery (jquery 1.6+ )

```
  $('input#idname').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: That's OK! I put all my functions inside the document.ready function together the jquery ui functions (dialog, tooltip), now I put out. Thanks

Comment: not working for me @bipen my code

$loc = $request->homeURL.'dashboard.php';
    ?>
         <script>
            $(function(){
                alertMessage();
            });
         </script>
     <?php other php code
and funcition alert message in js file
function alertMessage(){  
$(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();             
  
   myFunction: jNotify($(this).attr('class'),{
         VerticalPosition : 'center',
         HorizontalPosition : 'center'} ); 
   
});
}

Comment: @bipen mate help me out

Comment: @bipen here is my question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23192091/calling-jquery-function-after-certain-php-script-with-parameters