# Calling jquery function after certain php script with parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my php code where i am calling the jquery function:

*php code*

```
?>
     <script>
        $(function(){
            alertMessage('<?php echo $response ?>');
        });
     </script>
 <?php
   ...more php code...
```

and the function in javascript file seems like this

```
function alertMessage(variable){        
$(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();             

        myFunction: jNotify($(this).attr('class'),{
                                VerticalPosition : 'center',
                                HorizontalPosition : 'center'} ); 

});
}
```

Might be wrong way to do but how can I do this with php parameter in function call.
Really Stucked..

Possibly like this [Call jquery function from php page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568464/call-jquery-function-from-php-page), but not working.

Comment: In which function do you want to pass that php parameter ? is it alertMessage(); ??

Comment: @AbdUlAziz yes it is the alertMessage(php variable). then use it in the function further.

Comment: Is alertMessage('<?php echo $variable ?>') ?

Comment: @X-Man have you tried it like this ?                                          ?>
     <script>
        $(function(){
            alertMessage('<?php echo $variable ?>');
        });
     </script>
 <?php
   ...more php code...

Comment: am i defining the function in the js file in the right way or some thing wrong there because its not working @AbdUlAziz

Comment: @X-Man I think your function definition should accept a parameter, like this :                                                                      function alertMessage(param){        
$(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();             

        myFunction: jNotify($(this).attr('class'),{
                                VerticalPosition : 'center',
                                HorizontalPosition : 'center'} ); 

});
}

Comment: @AbdUlAziz man this is not the problem as the function call is not working.please write working function call or error!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of function call must need an element as parameter. this

```
myFunction: jNotify($(this).attr('class')
```

line shows that there must be an element on whom this function is performed.
so u can use the above function call as the same but cannot do what you are doing now i.e
the

```
jnotify
```

action. it must take some element to perform this action.

Comment: Absolutely that's what going wrong with me after all the efforts. Thanks for Correction